# Postgres db data deletion not reducing the table size

Tags: postgresql, data-cleaning

I have a postgres db with its size constantly increasing due to ~70 gb of data size and ~305 indexes size. So we planned a cleanup of older data,even after cleanup of data for 14 months and keeping 6 month data but data size and indexes size doesn't seems to be freeing up.

Please suggest anything if I am missing as I am new to postgres db.

Comment: You should really ask this in https://dba.stackexchange.com and instead of "huge data" and "huge indexes size" use actual real measurements.

Comment: Read  all the information in [VACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html).